# An advertisement system suitable for ajax applications

Tags: ajax, web-applications, ads

I've been just wondering if there is any good system suitable for use in ajax applications on per time basis. Things like AdSense are not the best fit as you don't want to force user to reload page every minute or so. What I'm looking for is some widget that possibly rolls advertisements every x seconds/minutes and counts the work accomplished accordingly.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a bit too simplistic, but why not do exactly as you just said? Use AJAX to call an advert script server-side that returns new content every n seconds? Pass in parameters such as location on the page / width / height etc. I guess it depends how complicated you want to make things and what format your content is in.